# Use JavaScript to delete records from MySQL table

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm currently building a webpage with the purpose to mirror a certain table in a MySQL server. This is what the page currently looks like.

[image]

For each row of the table, there are two buttons, and the red one should be able to delete the record from the server.

I've managed to use frontend JavaScript to pull the data from the server and build the table using "innerHTML" with this code:

```
async function loadData(){
    var result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/dados",
        {
            method:"POST",
            headers:{'Content-Type': "application/json"},
            body:JSON.stringify({command: "fetch", codMovimento: 0})
        }
    )
    tableJson = await result.json()
    console.log(tableJson)

    var table = document.getElementById("minhaTabela");

    table.innerHTML += "<tbody>"
    table.innerHTML += `<thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Código</th>
        <th scope="col">Tipo de Movimento</th>
        <th scope="col">Técnico</th>
        <th scope="col" style="width:350px;">Peça</th>
        <th scope="col">Código da Peça</th>
        <th scope="col">Origem</th>
        <th scope="col">Destino</th>
        <th scope="col" style="text-align: center;">Quantidade</th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
        <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>`

    for(var i=0; i < tableJson.length; i++){
        table.innerHTML +=
        `
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">${tableJson[i].CodMovimento}</th>
            <td>${tableJson[i].TipoMovimento}</td>
            <td>${tableJson[i].Tecnico}</td>
            <td>${tableJson[i].NomePeca}</td>
            <td>${tableJson[i].CodPeca}</td>
            <td>${tableJson[i].Origem}</td>
            <td>${tableJson[i].Destino}</td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">1</td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="approveButton${i}">
                <img src="/assets/check.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="32" height="32">
                </button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="refuseButton${i}">
                <img src="/assets/x.svg" alt="Bootstrap" width="32" height="32">
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        `
    }

    table.innerHTML += "</tbody>"

    declareButtons(tableJson)

}

loadData()
```

Now, I'm trying to define the onClick function for the red button, using this code:

```
async function declareButtons(tableJson){
    const approveButtons = []
    const refuseButtons = []
    
    for(var i=0; i < tableJson.length; i++){
    
        approveButtons.push(document.getElementById(`approveButton${i}`));
        approveButtons[i].onclick = async function(){
            console.log("Teste234")
        }
    
        refuseButtons.push(document.getElementById(`refuseButton${i}`));
        refuseButtons[i].onclick = async function(tableJson){

            console.log(tableJson[i].CodMovimento)
            var result = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/dados",
                {
                    method:"POST",
                    headers:{'Content-Type': "application/json"},
                    body:JSON.stringify({command: "delete", codMovimento: tableJson[i].CodMovimento})
                }
            )

            location.reload()

        }
        
    }
}
```

However, when pressing one of the red buttons, I get the following error:

[image]

I've tried using try/catch blocks inside the onClick function, which makes the error stop appearing, but then the button still does not work as expected (the code to delete the record is not executed).

Does anybody know how I could implement this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the `for` loop, use `let i = 0` instead of `var i = 0`. That will deal with the loop variable problem, though there may be other bugs to fix.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the reply. I did that, but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: Well the issue with using `var` instead of `let` is that all of the event handlers will *share* the same variable `i`. When the initialization loop finishes, the value of `i` will be beyond the end of the array, and that's where the error comes from. With `let`, there is a *separate* `i` for each iteration. You can add `console.log(i)` before the current `console.log()` you already have to verify that `i` is correct.

Comment: You might want to show your backend code that actually deletes the record from the DB. Your `fetch` sends a `command: delete` key/value to some backend API, but how does that work? Perhaps the problem is there?

Comment: @cssyphus the error is rising from the line "console.log(tableJson[i].CodMovimento)", right before calling the fetch function. Even if I delete the fetch part, the error persists, so the problem is not coming from the backend.

Comment: @Pointy thanks, I have applied the correction to the code, but I'm still getting the same exact error as before, so I don't think this error was particularly coming from that.

Comment: Have you verified that the value of `i` is correct? The error means that `tableJson[i]` is `undefined`. That could be cause by an incorrect value of `i`, or it could be that `tableJson` has been modified elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've accidentally masked the tableJson data you want with a different object.

```
async function declareButtons(tableJson){
// ....
    console.log(tableJson) // this will be the table JSON object
    refuseButtons[i].onclick = async function(tableJson){
        console.log(tableJson) // this will be the click event
```

onclick handlers receive an event object.  In `declareButtons` tableJson will contain whatever you passed to `declareButtons`... but  inside that onclick handler, `tableJson` now refers to the click event object instead.

You could use a different name for the event object in the function definition, or just remove it altogether:

```
async function declareButtons(tableJson){
// ....
    refuseButtons[i].onclick = async function(e){
        console.log(tableJson) // this will be the original tableJson
        console.log(e) // the click event object
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by declaring the variable containing the table information as a global variable, instead of local (var tableJson)

Comment: That'll work, but you'll likely regret it later. Best to avoid polluting global